# sqlalchemy вставка в массив в конкретный объект

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

[image: База данных]

Есть, например вот такая таблица. Как при помощи sqlalchemy вставить еще одно или несколько значений в, например, объект с id 3?

Answer (score 0):

Я не специалист, но считается плохой идеей сохранять списки, словари, множества и т.д. в бд таким образом. Возможно вам следует иначе спроектировать модель. Насколько я понимаю сейчас вы держите в колонке data строки и можете обращаться с ними как со строками при помощи [.update](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update)

Не забудьте закомитить изменение, аля `session.commit()`.

Comment: Уже решил проблему, храню данные в `jsonb` формате